# How to fix the Duration time in Jenkins? It is showing in yr

Tags: jenkins

I created a new Jenkins server, but I noticed the duration of the main class is in yr. When I go to classes bellow it it correct in hr/min.

Jenkins version 2.190.1
I didn't find this option in configuration.

Jenkins: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iNkK.png

Comment: This information is taken from unit test result xml. I would investigate whether the result in file is correct.

Comment: I used the same tests in an old Jenkins (version 1.625.1) and the duration is in hr/min there. I installed a new server because we need to use JaCoCo plugin. Anyways, I took a look in build/test-results/*.xml and didn't find the duration there.